# Show that the group of bijectives functions is not commutative

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $X$ (finite or infinite) be a set and $G=$ Sym$(X)$ be the group of bijections $f$ such that $f: X\to X$. Here the operation is composition and the identity element is the identity function $id: X\to X$. If $X$ has 3 or more elements, show that $G$ is non-commutative.

My approach:
My idea was that if I can just construct two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f$∘$g$ ≠ $g$∘$f$ for any $n$ (finite or infinite) then I would be done.

I tried constructing my $f$ as a function that fixes $n-1$ but moves all the rest of the positions and $g$ as a function that fixes $1$ but moves all the other positions. I am not sure if these will work or if I am on the right track.

I am not sure if my proof/functions will work or if I am on the right track.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are writing $f(g)$ but you do not mean that (nor does it make any sense, of course)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: The real clue is the condition $|X|\ge 3$: this suggests that you can do it for a $3$-element subset of $X$, and once you’ve done that, you can extend the functions to any larger set by setting $f(x)=g(x)=x$ for any other element of $X$. If $x_0,x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct elements of $X$, consider letting $f$ permute them cyclically, while $g$ interchanges two of them and does nothing to the third.

Comment: Could I let $f$ be the permutation $(1 2 3)$ and $g$ be the permutation $(1 2)$? Sorry I'm very new to the proofs/group theory. I think this would satisfy $f(x)=g(x)=x$ for any other elements of $X$ outside of $x_0, x_1, x_2$.

Comment: @user282639: Remember that $X$ is an arbitrary set of cardinality at least $3$, so you can’t assume that it contains $1,2$, and $3$. However, you have the right idea: take $f$ to have the cycle representation $(x_0\,x_1\,x_2)$ and $g$ to be the transposition $(x_0\,x_1)$, and you’ll find that they do what you want.

Comment: Would I need to show more work? Or does it suffice to just construct these two functions?

Comment: @user282639: You need to construct them for arbitrary $X$ with $|X|\ge 3$, which we’ve basically done now, and then verify that no matter what $X$ is, $f\circ g\ne g\circ f$, which is pretty straghtforward: just work out what the composite functions do to $x_0,x_1$, and $x_2$.

Comment: I see, just showing the 3 numbers that the functions vary at should do. Thank you!

Comment: @user282639: You’re welcome!